# Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I am getting this error message in the extension I develop for Chrome.

I have an iframe implemented in a html file

```
<iframe class = "main" id = "iframe" src = "" width = "515" height = "581" scrolling = "yes" frameborder = "0" ></iframe>
```

And I set the src of the iframe to a certain value when the extension icon is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").src = host_domain+"index.php?xxxx&yyy";
```

The strange thing is that I get this error really randomly, sometimes it is there and sometimes it is not there even though I have changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem:

This:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Had to be after the part where my iframe is defined in the html file.

I really see that it was a stupid thing to have it before creating the iframe but for some reason I never paid much attention to this code snippet. Maybe someone can explain why the script worked in 90% of the time and only failed randomly. Somehow the iframe had to be created simultaneously when the js script was executed even though the js code was implemented some rows above the iframe script.